# Page navigation in a C++ Windows Phone application?

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8.1

In my click handler

```
     void uni81::MainPage::proceed_click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    if (this->Frame != nullptr)
    {
        this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(activity2::typeid));
    }
}
```

I also added the following import/include statements

```
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop;
#include "activity2.xaml.h"
```

But when I run the program I get a nullReferenceError.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: try to use ---   this->Frame->Navigate(activity2::typeid);